# Retain cycle in a closure Swift

Tags: swift

I can see many examples of retain cycles in Swift. However many of them are incorrect, and reading the documentation does not make really simple examples that I can follow.

For the example:

```
class Dog {
    func bark() {
        print ("YAP")
    }
}

var dog = Dog()
let doSomething = {
    dog.bark()
}

doSomething()
```

Does the closure doSomething cause a retain cycle? I understand that the closure will execute quickly, but that is not the question. Does this inherently cause a retain cycle?

Comment: The example is too artificial. It won’t compile except in a playground, and there are no retain cycles in a playground.

Comment: @matt Actually you can recreate / simulate a retain cycle with `deinit` implementation and a `do { }` block to emulate a scope. It is a bit hacky though

Comment: @matt The example compiles fine if you put it in `main.swift` and run `swiftc main.swift`. Then `./main` to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no retain cycle in the program you posted.

#### What is a retain cycle?

Consider each object (including each closure) in your program as one vertex in a directed graph. Consider a strong reference from object (or closure) A to object (or closure) B as an edge from A to B in the graph.

A retain cycle is a cycle in the graph: a path containing at least one edge (strong reference) that leads from a vertex back to itself.

For example, a typical retain cycle looks like this:

[image: retain cycle from ViewController to View to Closure back to ViewController]

A view controller always has a strong reference to its view (if the view has been loaded). In this example, the view controller created a closure. The closure captured (has a strong reference to) the view controller. The view controller then stored the closure in a property on the view, creating a retain cycle.

#### What is the retain graph of your program?

Here's the retain graph of your program:

[image: retain graph showing doSomething referencing dog]

There are no retain cycles in this graph.

Comment: Maybe we should start calling them *ownership cycles* because `retain` is not manually called in Swift. Apple calls them *strong reference cycles* now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another "example" that runs outside of playground to showcase a retain cycle with a closure:

```
class ClosureClassStrongRefCycle {

    let str : String

    lazy var printStr: () -> () = { // self is captured
        print("\(self.str)")
    }

    init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }

    deinit {
        print("ClosureClassStrongRefCycle is being deallocated")
    } 
}
```

Now when you call your class like this :

```
 do {

      let myClassWithClosureStrongCycle = ClosureClassStrongRefCycle(str: "closure class strong cycle")
      myClassWithClosureStrongCycle.printStr()

 } // 'myClassWithClosureStrongCycle' is NEVER deallocated -> Strong reference cycle between this class and it's closure
```

the instance of `ClosureClassStrongRefCycle` retains itself because the closure within it retains `self`

finally if you want to get rid of the retain cycle, you can add `unowned self` like this :

```
lazy var printStr: () -> () = { [unowned self] in // Unowned copy of self inside printStr
    print("\(self.str)")
}
```